# Traversing related List - Error

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup

```
trigger ABCD on Account(after insert, after update) {
    List < Account > AccList = [Select id, (Select Id, Status__c from Clients__r) from Account WHERE Id IN: trigger.new];
    for (Account acc: AccList) {
        Integer Field1 = 0;
        for (Client__c pc: acc.Clients__r) {
            If(Status__c != 'Lapsed') {
                Field1=Field1+1;
            }
            acc.Field1__c = Field1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Purpose -**

I want to increase the count of a people in the object Account which has a lookup with another object. So I want to traverse the related list records, check if a field value is equal to lapsed, if No - increase the count.

**Error -**

> Didn't understand relationship 'LookupNameinAccount__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

**Question -**

1. I was reading articles on the relationship name . But not sure what
   exactly I need to use . I am currently using the name in the Fields
   section .
2. Is this code overall okay?

Comment: You have to give the PluralForm of the Custom Object appending __r for this kind of scenarios like If the Object Name is Student__c you have to give Students__r in that part of Query call

Comment: You should not give the Object Field directly like that. First Take one variable Integer demoField = 0; and do your business logic of Incrementing and Finally use that demoField value to the Object Field Value. According to your scenario, you are using After Insert and After Update, So you should use the DML operation of Update accordingly....

Comment: Field1__c belongs to which object? Either Account or Another Object used in it?

Comment: @Subhash- Field1 is the field in Account whose count needs to be increased after traversing the Status field in the related records of the lookup object. Can you please help me with the syntax to correct the traversing in lookup object ?for (LookupObject__c pc: acc.LookupNameinAccount) {
Say my lookup object/relationship name are both Client

Comment: Check my below answer. It will work for your scenario...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this directly with one trigger. Because it will gives the Recursion if you use the Update DML directly

Try the below procedure

**Apex Class** (Which will be used to stop the Execution of Trigger more than once)

```
public class RecursiveClass {
    public static boolean updateOnce = false;
}
```

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger ABCD on Account (after insert, after update) {
    if(RecursiveClass.updateOnce == false){
        RecursiveClass.updateOnce = true;
        List<Account> AccList = [Select id, Field1__c, 
                                        (Select Id, Status__c 
                                   from Clients__r) from Account WHERE Id IN: trigger.new];
        List<Account> updateList = new List<Account>();
        Integer demoField = 0;
        for (Account acc: AccList) {
            for (Client pc: acc.Clients__r) {
                 /* Change the Status based on your condition because In coding you given 
                 Not equal to 'Lapsed' but in Explanation you have given 
                 Equal to 'Lapsed'. Change that according to your scenario.
                 */
                If(pc.Status__c != 'Lapsed') {
                    demoField++;
                }
            }
            acc.Field1__c = demoField;
            updateList.add(acc);
        }
        if(updateList.size()>0){
            update updateList;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this might helps...

Comment: Thanks for the update . However the SOQL is returning Null for the Related object fields. i.e Select id, Field1__c, (Select Id, Status__c from Clients__r) from Account . Here Id/Status of  Client object is returned null. And it has records . Any reason why so?

Comment: Did you try Debugs, It will work perfectly if your related object has records in it...Please check your Related records once.

Comment: -Thanks . It's working. If I want to update the field , once any record in related list  is added , what changes needs to be done? Because then , the trigger wont be fired , but I would like the count to be updated as per my requirement..

Comment: Is your problem solved? And Sorry, I can't understand what you ask... Can you please explain clearly what you want?

Comment: My requirement  is - I have Account and Client object in Lookup relationship.  Client has a field Status . If Status!=Lapsed ,  count in a field in Account needs to be increased . So  if a new record is added to Client with Status!= Lapsed , the field must be updated +1 .

Comment: ohh... Then you should write a Trigger on Client Object not on Account Object. Ok Why you want to use the After Trigger. Lets clarify that one too... Is there any Specific Reason to use the After Trigger on this Account Trigger...?

Comment: No particular reason . Please correct me if it's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40529/discussion-between-subhash-and-sfdcrookie).